# What does $(X'X)^{-1}$ matrix mean in regression?

Tags: regression

In a regression what is the matrix $(X'X)^{-1}$? What do its interior elements represent?

Comment: I do believe that $(X'X)^{-1}$ is the covariance-variance matrix where each diagonal is the variance of $B_{i}$ and the other elements are co variances between different $\beta$'s. Unfortunately, I do not use Stata so I can't help you with your other question but maybe someone more informed can tel you :) Welcome to the site!

Comment: Yes, that is the covariance matrix. The other one X * X' is called the Gram matrix and is useful when finding the dual solution.

Comment: Try `matrix list e(V)` right after you have run the `reg` function.

Comment: Duplicate of this question? http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/73463/3277

Comment: There is also a discussion of the role of $(X'X)^{-1}$ in regression here: http://blog.stata.com/2011/03/03/understanding-matrices-intuitively-part-1/

Comment: I stumbled across this question just after providing an answer to it at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104704. To summarize, although this matrix is *not* the covariance matrix of the estimates of the regression coefficients, a scalar multiple of it is the covariance matrix. Because that multiple is usually not known, it typically is estimated (from the variance of the residuals). The square roots of the diagonal elements are routinely reported in regression output (as the "standard errors" of the coefficients).

Comment: The linear equation for multiple input/output system, the vector equation for a single input / output pair (x, y) can be written as y=Ax.  For multiple samples, (X, Y) it can be more convent to write  Y = X A'.  This can be solved for A with X' Y = X' X A  then (X' X)^(-1) X' Y = A.  The term (X' X)^(-1) X is the input, and can be processed using singular value decomposition to determine how many states the input represents, which tells the rank of A, which may be unknown.  So, without measuring any output information, the rank can be determined from the information contained in inputs only.