# Understanding the marginal distribution of multivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, matrix, matrix-inverse

I am trying to better understand the multivariate normal distribution.

Here I try to refer to the [conditional distribution part of wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) also the fifth page of [this tutorial](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~nando/540-2013/lectures/l6.pdf).

I do not quite understand what does the inverse of covariance matrix actually mean.

\begin{equation}
\mu=\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_{1} \\
\mu_{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{11} \Sigma_{12}\\
\Sigma_{21} \Sigma_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\Lambda=\Sigma^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\Lambda_{11} \Lambda_{12}\\
\Lambda_{21} \Lambda_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

*The distribution of $x_{1}$ conditional on $x_{2}$ is multivariate normal distribution, and we can get mean and variance using the partition of the
covariance matrix and the inverse covariance matrix.*

But my problem is, what does the inverse of covariance matrix mean? I do not quite understand this inverse operation, and also cannot understand how to derive the formula for mean and variance of the conditional probability.

I found a similar question here. [What does the inverse of covariance matrix say about data? (Intuitively)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73463/what-does-the-inverse-of-covariance-matrix-says-about-data-intuitively)
But still do not quite understand why partition here and how the conditional prob is derived.

Comment: Inverse of a covariance matrix is also called ``precision''.

Comment: Maybe it helps to have a look at the wikipedia article "Invertible matrix": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'll preface by saying I'm not entirely sure whether the issue here is comfort with matrix inversion, or its interpretation for this statistical purpose.

That said I think a good way to approach the precision matrix, is through what we can do with it.

**Conditionals**

$ \bf z = \left[ \begin{matrix}
    \bf x \\
    \bf y
  \end{matrix} \right]
  \sim \mathcal N \left( 
  \left[ \begin{matrix}
    \bf a \\
    \bf b
  \end{matrix} \right]
  ,
  \left[ \begin{matrix}
    \boldsymbol \Lambda_{aa} & \boldsymbol \Lambda_{ab}\\
    \boldsymbol \Lambda_{ab}^T & \boldsymbol \Lambda_{bb}
  \end{matrix} \right]^{-1}
  \right) \\$

Then the conditional has a nice form:

$\bf x | \bf y  \sim \mathcal N \left( 
  \bf a + \boldsymbol \Lambda_{aa}^{-1}\boldsymbol \Lambda_{ab}(\bf y - \bf b)
  , \ \
  \boldsymbol \Lambda_{aa}^{-1}
  \right) \\$

Things to observe:

1. If $\boldsymbol \Lambda_{ab}$ is zero, $\bf x$ is conditionally independent of $\bf y$. This is useful for modelling sitatuations where, for example, elements of $\bf z$ represent readings at different locations, but the value at each location is only linked to its close neighbours and not to locations far away.
2. If $\bf x$ is univariate, $\boldsymbol \Lambda_{aa}^{-1}$ is very easy to find (1/scalar).

**Reverse conditionals**

Suppose $\bf A$ is a matrix of constants (often provided by a given covariance matrix), and we are given two random vectors along with a prior for one and a conditional/likelihood for the other. See Bishop PRML p.93:

$ \bf y \sim \mathcal N(\bf b, \ \  \boldsymbol \Lambda_{bb}^{-1} ) \\
  \bf x | \bf y  \sim \mathcal N \left( 
  \bf A \bf y + \bf a, \ \ \boldsymbol \Lambda_{aa}^{-1}
  \right) \\ $

Then we can obtain the reverse conditional and the other marginal:
$ \bf x \sim \mathcal N(\bf A \bf b + \bf a, 
  \ \  \boldsymbol \Lambda_{aa}^{-1} +  \bf A \boldsymbol \Lambda_{bb}^{-1} \bf A^T ) $

$ \bf y | \bf x \sim \mathcal N \left( 
  \left( \boldsymbol \Lambda_{bb} +  \bf A^T  \boldsymbol \Lambda_{aa} \bf A \right)^{-1} 
  \left( \bf A^T \boldsymbol \Lambda_{aa} (\bf x - \bf a ) + \boldsymbol \Lambda_{bb} \bf b \right)
  , \ \ \left( \boldsymbol \Lambda_{bb} + \bf A^T  \boldsymbol \Lambda_{aa} \bf A \right)^{-1}
  \right) $

To see how we might use this suppose $\bf y$ is a common flight path used by planes, and $\bf x$ is the route taken by a particular plane. So that $\bf x | y$ is the route taken by a particular plane, given which path it is on. Then we would think about $\bf y | x$ if we had seen a particular plane flying and wanted to get a picture of what path the pilot was trying to follow.

If we take a simple case where $\bf A = I$ and $\Lambda_{aa}=a \bf I$,$ \Lambda_{bb}=b \bf I$ then:

$ \bf y | \bf x$$ \sim \mathcal N \left( 
  \left( b +  a \right)^{-1} 
  \left( a \left(\bf{x} - \bf{a} \right) + 
   b \bf{ b} \right)
  , \ \ \left( b + a \right)^{-1}
  \right) $

At which point you might notice that if $b >> a$ then the mean of $\bf y$ is much closer to its marginal mean. Whereas if $a >> b$ the mean of $\bf y$ gets moved far more in the direction of the difference of $\bf x$ from its mean.

Hence if $\bf x$ is our observed data, and the information about $\bf y$ our prior, then if $b>>a$ we have a strong prior. That is the data would have to be extremely unusual in order to change our beliefs about the distribution of $\bf y$.

**Derivations**

I'd suggest checking out the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity).

https://github.com/pearcemc/gps/blob/master/MVNs.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I tried to search more information to understand this. Thanks for the comments above, though  those were not what I do not understand.

The joint distribution is as below:

$$ g(x)=(2\pi)^{-p/2}|\Sigma|^{-1/2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^\intercal\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}$$

Here we have already used the Lambda(inverse of covariance matrix).Since the covariance matrix is a positive definite symmetric matrix,so it can be Cholesky decomposed.That means there exists L(a lower triangular matrix with real and positive diagonal entries),such that
$$\Sigma=AA^{*}$$
A^{*} denotes the conjugate transpose of L.Then we can conduct variable substitution.
Suppose
\begin{equation}
y=\begin{bmatrix}
y_{1}\ y_{2}\ ..y_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$y_{1},y_{2}...y_{n}\\$$individually identical distributed, and the follows the normal distribution with mean=0, variance=1
$$y\rightarrow x=\mu+A^{'}y$$

Then the determinant of the Jacobian transformation is
$$J(y\rightarrow x)=|A^{'}A|^{-1/2}=|\Sigma|^{-1/2}$$

Then
$$g(x)=f(y(x))J(y\rightarrow x)$$

Based on this vector form of joint distribution, we can calculate the marginal distribution of each variable, also the posterior distribution(or to say conditional distribution)

I am previously always stuck on the stage transitioning from one-dimension to mutli-dimension using vector form. For here we use a combination of some concepts from linear algebra:

- (1)positive definite symmetric matrix
- (2)Cholesky decomposition
- (3)eigenvalue,eigenvectors,eigenspace